# The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined on npm run deploy to gh-pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, github-pages

I was trying to deploy a react application to gh-pages. I've done it before, but this is the first time I'm getting this kind of error. It says

The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

I tried removing the node_modules folder and reinstalled all the packages with npm install, but still finding the same error

Below is my package.json file

```
{
      "name": "qrummy",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "homepage": "https://quiph.github.io/QRummy/",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "firebase": "^6.2.4",
        "gh-pages": "^2.1.0",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

And this is my main index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Error Output is as follows

```
 qrummy@0.1.0 deploy /home/qtalkdev/Krunal/github/QRummy
> gh-pages -d build

The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! qrummy@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the qrummy@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/qtalkdev/.np`enter code here`m/_logs/2019-08-01T17_28_14_611Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314779/trying-to-deploy-my-react-app-with-gh-pages-but-got-this-error-message-the-fi

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like the current version is not working. I faced the same problem today. Uninstall gh-pages module. Installed version 2.0.1 and it worked.

Comment: yeah pretty amazing! To install do: `yarn add gh-pages@2.0.1`