# npm errors when I try to deploy website to github

Tags: html, node.js, github, npm, github-pages

getting errors in the terminal when trying to use npm to deploy a website on github

I have no idea what to try

```sh
PS C:\Users\user\modern_portfolio> npm run deploy
```

```
> modern_portfolio@1.0.0 deploy C:\Users\user\modern_portfolio
> gh-pages -d dist

The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! modern_portfolio@1.0.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the modern_portfolio@1.0.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-04T04_12_42_515Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you check what the log says?

Comment: Isn't it similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/57314473/6309, which is itself a duplicate?

Comment: the log doesn't make much sense to me X,x

Comment: that looks pretty similar to my problem! I can uninstall the gh-pages module like the helper said, but how do I install a specific version of gh-pages?

Comment: ha! I will answer my own question above...older versions can be installed by adding @ after gh-pages. example: npm i gh-pages@2.0.1

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! I am now able to publish to github. Thank you both for helping! If I could ask a parting question, do the logs in the npm-cache get dumped? I wanted to go back and see if I could discern anything from them, but it appears that they are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Newer version 2.1 has some issue. They are probably working on it. Revert back to 2.0.1.

- Reinstall Github pages with a specific version:

```
npm uninstall gh-pages

npm i gh-pages@2.0.1

npm run deploy // as usual
```